# Iterating over an XElement collection using 'ReplaceWith' only works if I use 'ToList()' first

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, iteration

This code works:

```
var element = XElement.Parse("<div><span><em>Content</em></span><span><em>Content2</em></span></div>");

var spans = element.Descendants("span").ToList();

foreach(var span in spans)
{
    span.ReplaceWith(span.Nodes());
}
```

This does not, giving the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.':

```
var element = XElement.Parse("<div><span><em>Content</em></span><span><em>Content2</em></span></div>");

var spans = element.Descendants("span");

foreach(var span in spans)
{
    span.ReplaceWith(span.Nodes());
}
```

The only difference is I have removed the 'ToList()' when creating the list of Descendant Nodes. Why is this?

IQueryable implements IEnumerable, and I thought iterating forced deferred execution, so why is 'ToList()' making a difference here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case, you're changing the collection `spans` while you're iterating over it, so bad things happen. Maybe it's trying to give you what it remembers to be the next `span`, but you've already removed it.

(In core collections like lists, you get an exception explicitly stating that the collection has been modified. For example, in a `List<.>`, there's a version number that changes every time the list is modified; when you call `ToNext` on a list enumerator, if the version has changed, an exception is thrown.

In LINQ-to-XML it appears that the developers didn't add this kind of behaviour.)

In the first case, the list created by `ToList` isn't modified when you modify the original tree.

I'd try something like this:

```
XElement span = null; // or whatever class this should be
while ((span = element.Descendants("span").FirstOrDefault()) != null)
    span.ReplaceWith(span.Nodes());
```

i.e. replace the spans one by one, rather than trying to get them all in one go and then replace them.

Comment: It's not a "free" error - `List`, `Dictionary` etc. deliberately set some kind of flag when they are changed, and their iterators check the flag and deliberately throw an exception the next time you call `MoveNext` on them. The Linq-To-Xml developers just didn't bother to do this for some reason. (Maybe there are some useful changes you can make while iterating that don't cause an error?)

Comment: Thanks, the comment completes the picture for me.